# unable to insert into database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have below code in Laravel Model (class) to insert into database ,
but i get error: "

> PDOException in ... SQLSTATE[42000] :syntax error ...

```
public function Add_new($Desc, $Cat_Name, $Loc_Name, $Loc_Des, $Comment, $Ven_Name)
    {

        $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
                INSERT INTO itinv_category (name)
                VALUES (:Cat_Name);

                INSERT INTO itinv_location (name, Description)
                VALUES (:Loc_Name,:Loc_Des);

                INSERT INTO itinv_comment (text)
                VALUES (:Comment);

                INSERT INTO itinv_vendor (name)
                VALUES (:Ven_Name);

                SET @id1 = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM itinv_vendor);
                SET @id2 = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM itinv_comment);
                SET @id3 = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM itinv_location);
                SET @id4 = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM itinv_category);


                INSERT INTO itinv_inventory (category_id,location_id,vendor_id,comment_id,Description)
                VALUES (@id4,@id3,@id1,@id2,:Desc);
        ');
       $stmt->bindValue('Cat_Name', $Cat_Name);
        $stmt->bindValue('Loc_Name', $Loc_Name);
        $stmt->bindValue('Loc_Des', $Loc_Des);
        $stmt->bindValue('Comment', $Comment);
        $stmt->bindValue('Desc', $Desc);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the complete error message

Comment: Maybe SQL doesn't like a linebreak before `INSERT`.

Comment: @jens it was pdo which couldn't operate mutiple Mysql Queries , got the solution tanx for replying

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **Ven_Name**:

```
$stmt->bindValue('Ven_Name', $Ven_Name);
```

Comment: thanks for replying , i added as you said but did not work , i posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem , it was about ' pdo ' which can not operate multiple Mysql queries , we need to execute each query seperatley like below :

public function Add_new($Desc, $Cat_Name, $Loc_Name, $Loc_Des, $Comment, $Ven_Name)
    {

```
    // var_dump($Desc);

    $stmt1 = '                INSERT INTO itinv_category (name)
                    VALUES (\'' . $Cat_Name . '\')';
    $stmt2 = '
                    INSERT INTO itinv_location (name, Description)
                    VALUES (\'' . $Loc_Name . '\', \'' . $Loc_Des . '\')';
    $stmt3 = 'INSERT INTO itinv_comment (text)
                    VALUES (\'' . $Comment . '\')';
    $stmt4 = '         INSERT INTO itinv_vendor (name)
            VALUES (\'' . $Ven_Name . '\')';
    $stmt5 = 'SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM itinv_vendor';
    $stmt6 = 'SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM itinv_comment';
    $stmt7 = 'SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM itinv_location';
    $stmt8 = 'SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM itinv_category';


    $pdo = \DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt1);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt2);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt3);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt4);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt5);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $Ven_ID = $arr['0']['id'];


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt6);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $Comment_ID = $arr['0']['id'];


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt7);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $Loc_ID = $arr['0']['id'];


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt8);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $Cat_ID = $arr['0']['id'];


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO itinv_inventory (category_id,location_id,vendor_id,comment_id,Description)
                    VALUES (:Cat_ID,:Loc_ID,:Ven_ID,:Comment_ID,:Desc)');
    $stmt->bindValue('Cat_ID', $Cat_ID);
    $stmt->bindValue('Loc_ID', $Loc_ID);
    $stmt->bindValue('Comment_ID', $Comment_ID);
    $stmt->bindValue('Ven_ID', $Ven_ID);
    $stmt->bindValue('Desc', $Desc);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

}